# jqgrid search functionality

Tags: jqgrid

I am using jqgrid Advanced Search functionality in my project. I want to display the first overall row at all times irrespective of search. Is there a way how I can achieve this?

Comment: Could you insert JavaScript code? How the first row come in the grid (how you fill it)? Is it the row which contain data or it's something like summary row?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by first overall row?

Are you fetching details from a list or from a database?

You can use a Dataprovider object and use it's setSort method..

If the data is coming from a database this can easily be done by using the sort property to pass it as the sort by property in your sql statement, if you're using a list you can use Collections.sort() but your list object has to have a sorting algo that it should follow..